# Вопрос про .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

У меня имеется статический сайт с несколькими страницами html. Сайт - `site.com`
Страницы - `one.html, two.html, three.html`. Все они лежат в корне. Через .htaccess я смог убрать расширение html и следовательно страницы стали доступны по этим ссылкам - site.com/one, site.com/two, site.com/three. 
Но мне надо сделать таким образом - `site.com/one` и `site.com/two/three`. 
Мой .htaccess на данный момент:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html
```

Почему-то мне сказали переименовать html в php, но обязательно ли так? Появились сомнения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь можно обойтись без `.htaccess`.

- `one.html` переложите в каталог `one` и переименуйте файл в `index.html`.
- `two.html` переложите в каталог `two` и переименуйте файл в `index.html`.
- `three.html` переложите в каталог `two\three` и переименуйте файл в `index.html`.

Если статичные странички зачем переименовывать в php?